# Filament Only an edit page for a single record from the database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I followed the instructions from this [page](https://laraveldaily.com/post/filament-edit-only-single-record-custom-page), I try to improvise some things for my Filament project. I was lucky there was already a post over a week ago, but.

My problem is that, the text field won't load the value from the database to the `InputText` the attribute I want to get here is called,`rebate_value`. Here is what it looks like on the [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQeT5.png)
Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Z26.png) of the code of the page shown.
and here is what my [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggoBp.png) looks like.

here is the code of the `CustomerApplicationMaintenance`.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CustomerApplicationMaintenance extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'rebate_value',
    ];
}
```

I'm eager to learn this, Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did `CustomerApplicationMaintenance::all()->toArray()[0]` return?